# Make a Javascript Animation continue without resetting

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to get this function to be repeatable without resetting.
For example, when i press a button with this function, the button will move to the right from 0px to 100px. When I press the button again it will go from 100px to 200px and so on. It is supposed to animate as well, so it moves 1px at a time until the loop ends.

The code below only works as a one time use, as in it will move from 0px to 100px and pressing it again makes it go 0px to 100px.

I've been working on this for several hours and looked through many sources of help before asking.

```
function goRight() {
     var pos = 0;
     var count = pos;
     var elem = document.getElementById("main");
     var id = setInterval(move, 5);
     function move() {
          if(pos == count + 100){elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; clearInterval(id);}
          else {pos++; elem.style.left = pos + 'px';}
     }
}
```

Comment: can you show me where you're calling the function ?

Comment: <button id="main" onclick="goRight();">Right</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function goRight() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("main");                  // the element
    var origin = parseInt(elem.style.left) || 0;                 // get the left of the element (as an origin for the animation), 0 if not set yet
    var pos = 0;                                                 // pos initialized to 0

    var id = setInterval(move, 5);
    function move() {                                           
        if(pos == 101) { clearInterval(id); }                   // if pos is 101, then stop the animation
        else { pos++; elem.style.left = (origin + pos) + 'px';} // if not, then increment it and set the left of the element to pos + origin
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of using parseInt that way or using the pos as a value instead of the pixel amount. Works exactly how I wanted it too!

Comment: You're welcome! The trick was to get the value of `style.left` and add to it each time instead of starting from 0 again and again ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you must only make pos as a global variable and initiate it outside goRight function

like this:

```
var pos = 0;
function goRight() {
    var count = pos;
    var elem = document.getElementById("main");
    var id = setInterval(move, 5);
    function move() {
        if(pos == count + 100){elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; clearInterval(id);}
        else {pos++; elem.style.left = pos + 'px';}
    }
}
```

Whats wrong in your code is only every time you call goRight pos will be set to zero and again it will begin from start.

but with a global variable it will be save for next time interval will run.

Comment: Thank you, this works how I wanted it too and feels simple. I love coming here after hours of work only to feel dumb xD